# How to calculate pct_change in pandas with reference to just the first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 5, 2, 5, 6],
    "B": [-12, 23, 5, 22, 35],
    "C": [-32, 12, -10, 3, 2],
    "D": [2, 13, 6, 2, 8]
})
```

Now, I want to calculate the percentage change on `axis=1` but with reference to just `"A"` for all the columns like the percentage change for `"B"` w.r.t `"A"`, `"C"` w.r.t `"A"` and so on.

The `pct_change` function does a similar job but it calculates the percent change for successive rows or columns which I don't want.

Right now I'm thinking of acheiving this by probably a for loop and adding on the percentages OR splitting the dataframe like `["A", "B"]`, `["A", "C"]`, so forth and then applying `pct_change` to all separately.

The latter approach is I think better, but the question is,

**Is there an even better approach which will do the same job?**

Comment: Kindly add the expected output as well. `pct_change` also supports the parameters for `DataFrame.shift` and `Series.shift` so it might be possible achieving the required result using `pct_change`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [divide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html) function in pandas, diving all columns with column `A`

```py
pct = df.divide(df["A"], axis="index") - 1
pct.head()
```

Results:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0 | -13.000000 | -33.000000 | 1.000000 |
| 1 | 0.0 | 3.600000 | 1.400000 | 1.600000 |
| 2 | 0.0 | 1.500000 | -6.000000 | 2.000000 |
| 3 | 0.0 | 3.400000 | -0.400000 | -0.600000 |
| 4 | 0.0 | 4.833333 | -0.666667 | 0.333333 |

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate `pct_change` w.r.t. `A` easily with `DataFrame.sub` and `DataFrame.div` for your case.

```
df.loc[:, 'B':].sub(df['A'], axis=0).div(df['A'], axis=0)

           B          C         D
0 -13.000000 -33.000000  1.000000
1   3.600000   1.400000  1.600000
2   1.500000  -6.000000  2.000000
3   3.400000  -0.400000 -0.600000
4   4.833333  -0.666667  0.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ****kwargs** to `assign()`

```
    "A": [1, 5, 2, 5, 6],
    "B": [-12, 23, 5, 22, 35],
    "C": [-32, 12, -10, 3, 2],
    "D": [2, 13, 6, 2, 8]
})

basecol = "A"
df.assign(**{f"{c}_pct":df[basecol]/df[c] for c in df.columns if c!=basecol})
```

|  | A | B | C | D | B_pct | C_pct | D_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | -12 | -32 | 2 | -0.0833333 | -0.03125 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 5 | 23 | 12 | 13 | 0.217391 | 0.416667 | 0.384615 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | -10 | 6 | 0.4 | -0.2 | 0.333333 |
| 3 | 5 | 22 | 3 | 2 | 0.227273 | 1.66667 | 2.5 |
| 4 | 6 | 35 | 2 | 8 | 0.171429 | 3 | 0.75 |